# Writing spec for controller actions that return XML -- Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, testing, rspec

In my controller I have some methods which return json as well as xml data.
I need to test those actions. For testing the json part I found this [reference](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/specs-and-testing/writing-specs-for-controller-actions-that-return-json) and it is working fine. Now I am need of testing the actions for the XML part.
Anyone who can help or suggest something are most welcome I've been scratching my head for an hour now but to no avail.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you request your controller you specify the format you want. After parse the result with Nokogiri and see if your XML is valid or not

```
it 'should has tag hello' do
  get :index :format => :xml
  Nokogiri::XML(response.body).should has_tag('hello')
ebd
```

Comment: can we do it without using Nokogiri.

Comment: I found the answer myself. But still an upvote for your effort. Thanks

Comment: Even this works. Tested it this is working so it is a right answer, just that I don't want an extra tool in the environment

Answer (score 2):

@shingara thanks for the answer. But I wanted to do it without using any extra tools and just rspec.
I found the solution [here](http://railsontherun.com/2007/10/31/how-to-test-a-xml-builder-view/). Read the complete post. It has what I want and also a bit demo of Hpricot.
Well anyways thanks for answering.

```
it 'should has tag hello' do
  get :index :format => :xml
  response.should have_tag("hello",'value inside hello tag')
end
```

Comment: Yes, you can do like that because HTML is an XML so it's use the ActiveSupport::XML this can be Nokogiri or another tool too.

Comment: @Rohit link is broken :(

Comment: Sorry mate. I guess someone else has taken over the domain. :-(